# For protecting a WebApi, how do I choose between UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication vs. UseJwtBearerAuthentication vs.

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

There are many code samples showing how to protect a WebApi by registering authentication in Startup.cs, and they all use any one of the Owin Middlewares of UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication, UseJwtBearerAuthentication, UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication, or UseOAuth2Authentication.  But I cannot find any documentation explain how to choose which of these.  They all seem to set ClaimsPrincipal based on a Bearer token.

Are there times when one is appropriate over the others, or is it a random choice?

Answer (score 6):

Nan Yu is right, but there is another dimension in addition to .NET/.NET core and V1.0 vs V2.0: is it to protect a Web API or a Web Application:

- `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` is used in **ASP.NET
  Web API**s, using the Azure AD V1 endpoint (it requires V1 metadata)
- `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` is used in **ASP.NET Core Web API** (V1 endpoint indeed)
- `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` is used in **ASP.NET Web Apps**.
- `UseOAuth2Authentication` can be used in full.NET when talking to the V2 endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion , to protect web api by using bearer tokens from Azure AD , generally we can use both UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication extension method and UseJwtBearerAuthentication extension method in the OWN startup class .

In asp.net core ,you can directly use the Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer package . This package provides middleware that enables the application to receive OpenID Connect bearer tokens.Code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) is for your reference .

The usual WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticaitonMiddleware uses a
metadata endpoint which is not supported by the v2.0 endpoint . You could use UseJwtBearerAuthentication if using v2.0 endpoint . See code sample [here](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet) . In the code sample , it uses UseOAuthBearerAuthentication ,in asp.net core , it was renamed/replaced by the JWT bearer middleware .

Summary :

1. In .Net Framework using the Azure AD v1.0 endpoint, you'd better use `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`([code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect)) .
2. In Asp.net Core using the Azure AD v1.0 endpoint, you should use `UseJwtBearerAuthentication`([code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore)).
3. In .Net Framework using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint , you could use `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication`([code sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet)) or `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` .
4. In Asp.net Core using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint , you should use `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` .